Connect to SQL Server on host computer from SSMS within virtual machine
I'm working on a project where I am using a virtual machine (UTM) with Windows 11, from my Mac (M3 chip). Within the virtual machine I am using Visual Studio with an asp.net Ajax extension (unavailable on Mac) and also SQL Server Management Studio (unavailable on Mac). However, I cannot find a way to use SQL Server inside of the VM (SQL Server Express has errors installing, and Docker isn't working because I can't enable nested visualization). I do however have SQL Server through docker on my Mac and am able to get servers up and running.
So my question is, how can I connect to a SQL Server that I am hosting on the Mac, from SSMS within my virtual machine? I am not very familiar with SSMS or SQL Servers, so where would I start in resolving a problem like this?
As recommended I activated bridge mode for the VM and then attempted to connect to the server as I would if I were on the same machine as the server, using the name of the server, login, and password. I was given the following message:
Cannot connect to SQL_Server_Docker.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

I have also attempted using tcp:172.17.0.2 (the IP address of docker container) as the server name and have gotten a similar error
What should I change in my connection process in order to successfully connect to my server?

the vm must have a networking bridge to the host, to have a two way connection

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Name resolution isn't likely to work here unless you edit your hosts file inside the VM. Have you tried using the IP address of the host machine (as viewed from the VM)?

The docker container will have its own IP address, and you need to set up networking correctly for your VM.

172.17.0.2 isn't a routable address, it only exists and is accessible from within that Docker container's network. You published the container's port 1433 on the Docker host with something like docker run ... -p 1433:1433, right, so what's the IP address of your Docker host (the Mac)? Is that address accessible from within your VM?

Why not just install SSMS on the host machine too? You could connect directly that way and avoid this issue. Failing that, and assuming you can't get the networking to work, you could SSH from your VM to the host machine and map the remote port 1433. You'd need to enable TCP/IP protocols in Sql Server Configuration Manager too.

@JamesCockayne there's no SQL Server Management Studio for macOS, op would need to settle for an alternative tool that can run on macOS like DBeaver (which it seems like they're unable or unwilling to do).

@AlwaysLearning thanks. I didn't know that! In that case I would recommend VS Code and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver16
